# Unwanted line breaks in threeparttable's tablenotes

Tags: tables, line-breaking, threeparttable, tablenotes

I'm generally quite happy with the behavior of [`threeparttable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), but there sometimes appears unwanted line breaks in the table notes even though I'm using the `para` option. For instance, in the below MWE, there is an unwanted line break after the "a" note.

How can I ensure that there won't be any line breaks between notes?

Note that the MWE is just a sample table to illustrate the problem. More generally, I am able to generate these unwanted line breaks by incrementally adding a few words. (This suggests that one solution would be to rephrase the notes, but I would prefer not to have to do that.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}

      {
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r r}
          & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\
          Lorem\tnote{a} ipsum\tnote{b} dolor\tnote{c} sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit & 123 & 456
        \end{tabularx}
      }

      \begin{tablenotes}
        Note. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
        \item[a] Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        \item[b] Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        \item[c] Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a feature, so notes don't start at the end of a line.

I'll take this as a suggestion for a configurable parameter to control how much of the note needs to fit on its initial line. Without that convenience you are stuck redefining a macro.

```
\makeatletter
\def\TPT@doparanotes{\par
   \prevdepth\z@ \TPT@hsize
   \TPTnoteSettings
   \parindent\z@ \pretolerance 8
   \linepenalty 200
   \renewcommand\item[1][]{\relax\ifhmode \begingroup
       \unskip
       \penalty -45 \hskip\z@\@plus 10pt\penalty-19
       \hskip 25pt \penalty 9999 \hskip-25pt
       \hskip 1em\@plus3pt
      \endgroup\fi
      \tnote{##1}\,\ignorespaces}%
   \let\TPToverlap\relax
   \def\endtablenotes{\par}%
}
\makeatother
```

And if you *absolutely* need a flush right margin, it could be

```
\makeatletter
\def\TPT@doparanotes{\par
   \prevdepth\z@ \TPT@hsize
   \TPTnoteSettings
   \parindent\z@ \pretolerance 8
   \linepenalty 200
   \renewcommand\item[1][]{\relax\ifhmode \begingroup
       \unskip
       \hskip 1em\@plus3pt
      \endgroup\fi
      \tnote{##1}\,\ignorespaces}%
   \let\TPToverlap\relax
   \def\endtablenotes{\par}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That is a good way of taking my question :-) I think it is a good thing that notes don't start at the end of the line, but I felt that the default behavior was a little excessive. Thank you for your suggested alternatives.